# How to select distinct of the max here

Tags: sql, distinct

I have the following Table A & Table B, where A is one to many with B; for each record of A, i need to select the corresponding max record on B for each group for A.
i.e. grouping is done based on last_updated_time.

```
SELECT taba.ws_name, tabb.b2a,  max(tabb.last_update_time)
FROM TabA taba, TabB tabb
where taba.name = 'xyz'
and taba.id = tabb.b2a 
group by taba.ws_name, tabb.b2a
```

This works well and fine.

The problem arises when i need to select the "status" as well of the last transaction, this leads to selection of duplicates because status can either be failed or success.

*My requirement is to select only the max record irrespective of its status (though i need to display the status as well)*

So when ever any "ws_name" has multiple records of failure as well as success so the MAX updated_time gets selected for both groups (of "Failure" & "Success").

Below is the query which i tried and havent got  clue on how to remove the duplicates selected because of status.

```
SELECT taba.ws_name, tabb.b2a, **tabb.status**,  max(tabb.last_update_time)
FROM TabA taba, TabB tabb
where taba.name = 'xyz'
and taba.id = tabb.b2a 
group by taba.ws_name, tabb.b2a, **tabb.status**
```

Comment: My SQL brain turned off for the day when I got home from work, but does just selecting and not grouping by tabb.status give you an error?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson depends on the server type. "Strict" server, like postgres, will explode. "Lax" servers, like mysql, will not - in mysql's can it will return the *first* row encountered for each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you need to select the max values, then join onto this result to get the actual values you want.

For example:

```
SELECT     InnerQuery.*,
           TabB.Status

FROM      
            (SELECT     A.ws_name, 
                       B.b2a, 
                       max(B.last_update_time) AS MaxUpdatedTime

            FROM       TabA A
            INNER JOIN TabB B ON (A.id = B.b2a)

            GROUP BY   A.ws_name,
                              B.b2a) AS InnerQuery
INNER JOIN
            TabB ON (InnerQuery.b2a = TabB.b2A AND TabB.last_update_time = InnerQuery.MaxUpdatedTime)
```

InnerQuery gives you all the rows you want, except without the status. We therefore join back onto B to get the status for the matching rows.

i.e. we get all the rows in B we want then join back onto B to get the status value for those rows that we've uniquely identified, because, as you say, introducing status just gives us another level of grouping.

Comment: thanks, i had to add up a 'distinct' in the first select because 'MaxUpdatedTime' some times have same values for few and hence it was returning duplicates here as well based on max time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a nested SELECT:

```
SELECT
    X.*, B.status
FROM
    (SELECT
        taba.ws_name,
        tabb.b2a,
        max(tabb.last_update_time) AS maxtime
     FROM
        TabA taba,
        TabB tabb
     where
        taba.name = 'xyz' and taba.id = tabb.b2a
     group by
        taba.ws_name,
        tabb.b2a) X,
    tabb B
WHERE
    X.b2a = B.b2a AND X.maxtime = B.last_update_time
```

---

I would also use the join clauses. This is the 'modern' way of joining tables.

```
SELECT
    X.*, Y.status
FROM
    ( SELECT
          A.ws_name,
          B.b2a,
          max(B.last_update_time) AS maxtime
      FROM
          TabA A
          INNER JOIN TabB B
              ON A.id = B.b2a
      WHERE
          A.name = 'xyz'
      GROUP BY
          A.ws_name,
          B.b2a) X,
    INNER JOIN TabB Y
        ON X.b2a = Y.b2a AND X.maxtime = Y.last_update_time
```

I you replace the "INNER JOIN"s by "LEFT JOIN"s, you will also get results for records in TabA when there are no corresponding records in TabB.

Answer (score 0):

You may use CTE, in fact for this case is the same result using this and subqueries, but the diference is that (in my own opinion) this code is easier to read.

The first block (WITH) executes the query to obtain the max values and its corresponding ids, and stores the results in a "temporary table".

Then in the second query use the max values obtained in the result from the CTE query (the first one) and use them to restrict the results from your original query.

```
WITH TabB_CTE(b2a, last_update_time) as
(
    Select
        b2a, max(last_update_time) As last_update_time
    From
        TabB
    Group By b2a
)

SELECT 
    taba.ws_name, tabb.b2a, tabb.status, tabb.last_update_time
FROM
    TabA taba Join TabB tabb
        On  taba.id = tabb.b2a
    Join TabB_CTE tabc
        On  tabc.b2a = tabb.b2a
        And tabc.last_update_time = tabb.last_update_time
where taba.name = 'xyz'
```